# How can I style the Openstreetmaps?

Tags: leaflet, maps

Currently I'm using leaflet with Openstreetmaps. I would like to add some styling to the map for better look and feel and to match the theme of map with that of my application. I saw maputnik, mapbox etc which applies fees to use custom styles. Is there any free of cost method to do this?

Comment: I guess you should read https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/ first.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that what you use from OpenStreetMap in your Leaflet application is the free OpenStreetMap WMS. Thus, you should first get a basic knowledge of what a WMS is.

[From OSM wiki:](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS)

> WMS stands for Web Map Service. It's an OGC standard for serving up
> map images over HTTP.

In fact, what you get by using the OpenStreetMap WMS is the final product of this procedure:

> Spatial Data stored in a Database -> WMS Server -> WMS tiles

**WMS server transforms spatial data to georeferenced images and is responsible for the styling.**

Both the Spatial Database and the WMS Server belong to OpenStreetMap. What you get is the free tiles (images) served by their server. Therefore, the only styles you can apply to your map tiles is the ones you could apply to raster images (e.g. black & white filter). You cannot, for example, apply different styles for roads, building etc. This can only be done by the WMS server.

*Mapbox*, *Maptiler* and other providers, are actually using the OSM dataset and let you pick a style or even create a custom one. The styling is still done by their own WMS server. This is why these services are not totally free.

Therefore, your only options for custom WMS styles are:

- **Build your own WMS server**. This may  be a hassle and due to hardware requirements and possible security issues, it may not actually be as free as it sounds.
- **Use a third-party provider** (like the ones you mentioned) that may offer a free pricing plan with specific restrictions (e.g. tiles served per month).